# Exclude external dependent jars been take up during Spring Boot Configuration

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a spring boot project that is dependent on another spring project where my DTOs are defined as follows .

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.suvankar</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

my-core jar also internally have some Beans defined . I dont want to load any beans from my-core jar in my current project. I would only like to use DTO's present in my-core jar . How can i tell spring boot not to load any beans from my-core . 
Or is there any way in  maven by which i can include only the package that contains DTO's .

Comment: You can't only include the packages cause the package you have decided is the jar file which contains all this into a single thing. This in the end means you haven't correctly decoupled the information Beans and DTO's. so the best approach would be to make two different modules one which contains the Beans only and another which contains only the DTO`s...Furthermore I'm not sure why you need to have DTO's while using Spring boot...usually defines smaller apps and three tier architecture...?

Comment: I agree there should be a different module for DTO . But this my-core is a third party jar which i dont have any control . I have used name as my-core just for a symbolic reference .

Comment: In this case you are out of luck cause the creator of your jar does not really understand the need of it's customers...You can exclude a transitive dependency but only on the level of jar files not on class file level...neither Maven can help here not Java can help here in general...